# How to run a Canopy test suite with xUnit?

Tags: f#, xunit, ui-testing, canopy-web-testing

I decided to use [canopy](http://lefthandedgoat.github.io/canopy/) framework to test my UI.

Most of the examples include either [built-in assertion framework](https://github.com/lefthandedgoat/canopyStarterKit/blob/master/canopyStarterKit/tests/Elements.fs) or [Expecto](https://github.com/SAFE-Stack/SAFE-BookStore/blob/master/test/UITests/Tests.fs). Which are both good choices yet I use xUnit everywhere else in the project and want to be uniform for now.

For xUnit I have found only [this example](https://github.com/DanielOliver/CanopyExample/blob/master/Tests.fs) but it contains just two very basic tests whereas I need to things like common code to run prior to all the tests. What would be an idiomatic way for ***canopy + xUnit***?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xUnit has [class fixtures](https://xunit.github.io/docs/shared-context.html#class-fixture) and [here](https://marnee.silvrback.com/fsharp-and-xunit-classfixture) is an example how to bring it to F# code.

Combining that with canopy scenarios, here is an example of what it can look like:

```ml
open canopy.classic
open canopy.types
open System
open Xunit

let private openApp() =
    ...

type Fixture() =
    do
        start ChromeHeadless

    interface IDisposable with 
        member _.Dispose() =
            quit()

type Tests() = 
    interface IClassFixture<Fixture>

    [<Fact>]
    member _.``Soundcheck - Server is online``() =
        openApp()
        
    [<Fact>]
    member _.``Button1 is enabled``() =
        openApp()

        let button = element "#button1"

        Assert.True button.Enabled

    [<Fact>]
    member _.``Button2 is disabled``() =
        openApp()

        let button = element "#button2"

        Assert.False button.Enabled
```